# Take NSView or NSWindow screenshot programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, screenshot

I need to capture my NSView to an image. Making a capture of NSWindow will be also fine - I can just crop out the necessary view later.

I have two requirements:
(1) I have semi-transparent buttons on the view;
(2) I need to get a capture even if the view is partially out of the screen.

This is the view I want to capture:

[image]

I have tried these four methods, and none of them can do what I want.

Method 1.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[view dataWithPDFInsideRect:viewRect]];
NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
[imageData writeToFile:fName atomically:NO];
```

This method preserves button transparency but ignores its layer additions like a fancy border:

[image]

Method 2.

This is a recommended method to capture NSView contents:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:viewRect];
[view cacheDisplayInRect:viewRect toBitmapImageRep:imageRep];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:viewRect.size];
[image addRepresentation:imageRep];
NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
[imageData writeToFile:fName atomically:NO];
```

This method preserves layer features but ignores button transparency:

[image]

Method 3.

This method just renders the view layer into an image:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:viewRect.size];
[image lockFocus];
CGContextRef ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext].graphicsPort;
[view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
[image unlockFocus];
NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
[imageData writeToFile:fName atomically:NO];
```

This method also preserves layer features but ignores button transparency:

[image]

Method 4.

```
CGImageRef cgimg = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectZero, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, (int)self.window.windowNumber, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg size:viewRect.size];
NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
[imageData writeToFile:fName atomically:NO];
```

This methods preserves both layer features and button transparency, but if the view is partially out of the screen then it does not render that part which is out of the screen:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong? How can I get a screenshot just as the system screen capture utility does?

Comment: This is the most useful un-answered question on StackOverflow, given all the working code in your question which has been helpful to me.  I'm afraid I don't know the solution for grabbing the screen buffer just as it is - you understand there are security measures against looking at the raw screen buffer as you could be reading data from other apps' windows.

Comment: I've tried all your methods, but just to grab an NSImage to draw elsewhere, not to write to a file. I have found that method 1 never works for me, method 2 works in 10.14 & 10.15 but not 10.13, method 3 is too slow, and method 4 is perfect (for my use case the window is always totally onscreen. although it is obscured).